# Creating Temporary table in laravel/lumen and insert data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I want to create temporary table in Laravel/Lumen and I made schema like this.

```
Schema::create('temp_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('link');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->temporary();
});
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` I see...

```
Migrating: 2017_11_25_165640_create_temp_table
Migrated:  2017_11_25_165640_create_temp_table
```

... but it didn't create any tables. What happened?

Comment: which laravel version did you use?

Comment: its laravel 5.4

Comment: try `php artisan migrate --force`  check this documentation hope you will find the way: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#running-migrations

Comment: its create all the table except temporary table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Temporary tables` are session based. It is not created on `SQL Server`. You can have a look in [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-implement-temporary-table) article in **laracast**.

Temporary table can be used in `lumen` too. We can use `Schema Builder`
to `create` table and `drop` table.
Let assume, we have a function for a simple request. We could use `temporary table` like the following-

```
public function temporary_check()
{
    Schema::create('temp_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('sender_id');
        $table->integer('receiver_id');
        $table->string('message');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->temporary();
    });

    DB::table('temp_message')->insert(['sender_id'=>2,'receiver_id'=>3,'message'=>'message temp check']);

    $data = DB::table('temp_message')->get();

    Schema::drop('temp_message');

    return $data;
}
```

As `Temporary Table` are `session` based, you should always `free-up` `memory` by `dropping` tables at the end of your work.

Comment: are these table also available in lumen and if its session base do we need to create model to how do we insert and retrieve value from temp table

Comment: just have a look at the link, they have explained very well.

Comment: can't able to find nay solution there why i post wuestion here

Comment: Its just an example, you could use it in a much better way like creating start of a session and dropping table end of a session

Comment: really helpful .. i am using in lumen so no session can you please let me know when to expire this table and temp table can be created with migration and can we use in model cause i tired with model but i am getting error

Comment: you can use in model but need to ensure you are doing your query with this model when table is created. And until table is dropped. Like in this example you can change $data = DB::table('temp_message')->get(); to $data = Model::all();

Comment: my question is when ever need temp table need to create temp table again its not stay when i create it once its drop by its self after session.

Comment: you may create table at log in and drop at logout. It's your best interest which suites you.

Answer (score 1):

A **temporary table** is a special type of table that allows you to store a temporary result set, which you can reuse several times in a **single session**. So, if you are trying to find them, you probably won't get it as they are session-based.

`MySQL` removes the **temporary table** automatically when the session ends or the connection is terminated.

You should keep in mind that these tables are created without indexes, so if your goal is to improve the speed of queries, adding an index after creating the table is usually desirable.

You can read more about it: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/